# Intersection of neighborhood of identity is closure of identity.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $(G, .)$ be a group. Further assume that $G$ is endowed with some topology such that the map $G × G → G$ given by $(x, y) → xy$ and the map $G → G$ given by $x → x ^{−1}$ are continuous. In this case $(G, .)$ is said to be a topological group wrt the topology on it. Let $e$ be the identity element of $G$.

Let $H_0$ denote intersection of all neighbourhoods of identity. Prove that it is closure
of ${e}$.

Attempt  :

- $e \in H_0$
- If $x \in H_0=(\cap U_\alpha$ where $U_\alpha$ are neighbourhoods of identity), then $x \in U_\alpha,  \forall \alpha$ , so $x \in \bar e$ , $\bar e =$ closure of identity ${e}$, so $H_0 \subset \bar e$.
- Take $y \in \bar e  \setminus H_0$. Then $y \in \bar e$ but $\exists U_\beta$ such that $y \notin U_\beta$.  I'm done if I contradict this  isn't it? 
  Now , since $y \in \bar e$, any nbhd of $y$ say $U_y \cap \{e\} \neq \emptyset$, so, $\{e\} \in U_y \cap U_\beta$. So $\exists$ $V \subset U_y \cap U_\beta$ open which is a nbhd of $e$.

I don't know if I am doing it correct and how to proceed.

Comment: I do not clearly understand the approach there. Is there a simpler solution which just uses set theory? Or a different approach ?

Comment: Also how to show this $H_0$ is a subgroup of $G$ ?

Comment: @mathreadler I know that it is a possible duplicate and at the very beginning I flagged it as so, but Noob said he didn't understand that answer and asked for a different approach, that's why I removed my comment and added an answer. I would propose to give him time to edit his question..

Comment: @EnderWiggins: Yes I also prefer to judge that way mostly in case the asker did not understand the other duplicate question even though it's clear to the reviewer it's the same question, but this was one of the few times I didn't.

Comment: @mathreadler: Ok, I understand. (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for a different approach with respect to the one given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039907/closure-of-identity-element-in-a-topological-group-is-the-intersection-of-its-ne), I'll try to give you an answer, but maybe it would be appreciated if you edit your question in order to recognize you already read the previous answer and it was not the answer you were looking for.

Now let, as you did, $\left\{U_\alpha\mid \alpha\in I\right\}$ be the family of neighborhoods of $e$. Our approach will be the following: first we will show that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha$ is closed and secondly we will show that every closed $C$ in $G$ which contains $e$ must contain $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha$ as well.

For the first claim, if $x\notin \bigcap_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha$ then there exists $\beta\in I$ such that $x\notin U_\beta$. Since $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an homeomorphism, $U_\beta^{-1}=\{h^{-1}\mid h\in U_\beta\}$ is still an open neighborhood of $e$ and so $xU_\beta^{-1}$ is an open neighborhood of $x$. We claim that $xU_\beta^{-1}\cap U_\beta=\emptyset$. Assume by contradiction that $y\in xU_\beta^{-1}\cap U_\beta$. Then there exists $z\in U_\beta$ such that $y=xz^{-1}$, which implies that $x=yz\in U_\beta$; a contradiction. Therefore $G\setminus \bigcap_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha$ is open and hence $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha$ is closed.

Let us prove the second claim now. Assume that $e\in C$ for some closed subset $C$ of $G$. Pick a generic $x\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha$. The family of open neighborhoods of $x$ is of the form $\{xU_\alpha\mid \alpha\in I\}$. Since $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an homeomorphism, we can also write this family as $\{xU_\alpha^{-1}\mid \alpha\in I\}$. For every $\alpha\in I$, we have that $e=x\cdot x^{-1}\in xU_\alpha^{-1}$. Thus for every open neighborhood $xU_\alpha^{-1}$ of $x$, $e\in C\cap xU_\alpha^{-1}$ and so $x\in\overline{C}=C$. In conclusion, $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha\subseteq C$ as claimed.